# Splitting "X verbed Y into Z" statements into question and answer

Tags: conversation, responses

Are these responses grammatical?

1. > Speaker A: What did John force Mary to do?
   >   Speaker B: Her into buying the house.
2. > Speaker A: What did John talk to Jim?
   >   Speaker B: Him into believing the news.

The original sentences of speaker B are as follows:

1. John forced Mary into buying the house.
2. John talked Jim into believing the news.

And, if I give some context for them, is it possible to understand? such as:

> (Context: John wants Mary to buy the house, and then he has insanely talked to her for his goal.)
>
> Speaker A: What did John force Mary to do?
>   Speaker B: Her into buying the house.

Answer (score 4):

They're not quite right. A better construction would be like this:

1. > Speaker A: What did John force Mary to do? 
   >   Speaker B: Buy the house.
2. > Speaker A: What did John talk Jim into? 
   >   Speaker B: Believing the news.

OR, more formally, Speaker B might make a complete sentence in each case:

1. > Speaker A: What did John force Mary to do? 
   >   Speaker B: John forced Mary to buy the house.
2. > Speaker A: What did John talk Jim into? 
   >   Speaker B: John talked Jim into believing the news.

(Speaker B may also choose to say 'He' instead of 'John' in both statements, and/or use 'Her' and 'Him' for Mary and Jim.)

Note that *talking Jim into* something is NOT the same as merely *talking **to** Jim* about something. *Talking into* is an idiom for *convincing*.